# Tomcat opening a lot of instance in memory

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat6

Well, i have only one tomcat server started, but when i executed the command "htop" in my ubuntu server i saw that have 16 tomcat6 instances in memory with the exactly same "command" but PID different. See the image bellow:

[image]

Comment: I guess you have 16 tomcat6 instances in memory.

Comment: Those instances might not have been closed properly. I have see this with jboss frequently. I would suggest do kill on all tomcat process and then start fresh one. Some of the threads in your application are hanging there which might be preventing clean tomcat shutdown.

Comment: The same thing happens with "apache2". I have a lot of instances in memory.

Comment: Use kill -9 <pid> to stop tomcat instances and review your code, maybe here are some errors which hang threads, preventing JVM to stop properly

Comment: I don't have any application executing in TOMCAT, i just started the server with no application, just index.html to show "it's works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `htop` list threads instead of process, try to use `top` of `ps -ef | grep tomcat`

Comment: I think you correct, if i use "ps -ef | grep tomcat", i see only one instance of tomcat running.